# My speed goes down, what am I missing?

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I have designed 2 FSMs for CRC purposes. I got the base code (xor tree) from an online CRC generator, and build around it the FSMs, one for Tx and one for Rx. It works great. When I test either, ON ITS OWN, i get 200+ MHz speed. When I try to test them, back to back, my speed drops significantly (bellow 150 MHz). When I include them in the bigger design with a UART link, it drops even lower (110 MHz). 
I guess I am missing something very important, but have no idea what. Do you?
I have included the code for the Tx one. The Rx is very similar. And just to be more precise, the limiting factor when they are both tested is, frame-to-output(Tx) to curr_state(Rx). 
I should also say that i have recently started dealing with vhdl, so please point out any stupid mistakes i have in the design bellow. 
(ps. FSM state vector encoding is for another discussion, but any input will be more than welcome)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Append_Tx_FSM is
port (
CLK                 : in std_logic;                     -- system clock
RESETn          : in std_logic;                     -- global reset
APPEND_CRC          : in    std_logic;                      -- input flag
TX_FRAME_NO_CRC     : in    std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);      -- 40-bit input frame to attach CRC

CRC_APPENDED        : out std_logic;                        -- output flag
TX_FRAME            : out std_logic_vector(47 downto 0)         -- 48-bit output frame
  );
  end Append_Tx_FSM;
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   architecture arch of Append_Tx_FSM is
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- Finite State Machine declaration
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE State IS (idle_st, delay_crc, result)                                  
signal curr_st, next_st         : State;        
ATTRIBUTE syn_encoding : STRING;
ATTRIBUTE syn_encoding of curr_st : signal is "gray";
 --ATTRIBUTE syn_state_machine : boolean;
 --ATTRIBUTE syn_state_machine of curr_tx_st : signal is false;
                    -- state vector
signal crc_result_tx            : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);                -- signal for crc computation
signal last_append          : std_logic;                            -- signal for last value of input flag
signal frame_to_append          : std_logic_vector (39 downto 0);               -- signal for frame construction
signal frame_to_output          : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0);               -- signal for output
signal appended_crc         : std_logic;                            -- signal for output

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 begin
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  -- CRC computation for input data(39:0) Polynomial (1+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^5+x^8) (0x97)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CRC_RESULT_TX(0) <= '0' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(0) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(3) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(5) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(7) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(8) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(9) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(10) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(11) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(12) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(15) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(21) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(22) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(23) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(24) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(25) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(27) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(30) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(31) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(32) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(33) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(35) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(36) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(37) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(38);

CRC_RESULT_TX(1) <= '1' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(0) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(1) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(3) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(4) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(5) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(6) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(7) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(13) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(15) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(16) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(21) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(26) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(27) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(28) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(30) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(34) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(35) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(39);

CRC_RESULT_TX(2) <= '0' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(0) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(1) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(2) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(3) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(4) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(6) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(9) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(10) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(11) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(12) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(14) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(15) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(16) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(17) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(21) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(23) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(24) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(25) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(28) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(29) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(30) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(32) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(33) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(37) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(38);

CRC_RESULT_TX(3) <= '0' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(0) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(1) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(2) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(4) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(8) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(9) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(13) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(16) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(17) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(18) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(21) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(23) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(26) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(27) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(29) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(32) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(34) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(35) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(36) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(37) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(39);

CRC_RESULT_TX(4) <= '1' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(1) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(2) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(3) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(5) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(9) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(10) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(14) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(17) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(18) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(19) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(22) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(24) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(27) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(28) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(30) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(33) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(35) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(36) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(37) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(38);

CRC_RESULT_TX(5) <= '1' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(0) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(2) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(4) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(5) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(6) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(7) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(8) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(9) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(12) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(18) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(19) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(20) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(21) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(22) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(24) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(27) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(28) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(29) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(30) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(32) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(33) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(34) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(35) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(39);

CRC_RESULT_TX(6) <= '0' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(1) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(3) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(5) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(6) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(7) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(8) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(9) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(10) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(13) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(19) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(20) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(21) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(22) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(23) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(25) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(28) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(29) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(30) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(31) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(33) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(34) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(35) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(36);

CRC_RESULT_TX(7) <= '1' xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(2) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(4) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(6) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(7) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(8) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(9) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(10) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(11) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(14) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(20) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(21) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(22) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(23) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(24) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(26) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(29) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(30) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(31) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(32) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(34) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(35) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(36) xor TX_FRAME_NO_CRC(37);

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- At the desired clock edge, load the next state 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CurStDecode_RX:process (CLK, RESETn)
begin
-- Clear FSM to start state 
if (RESETn = '0') then
    curr_st <= idle_st;
elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then
    curr_st <= next_st;
end if;
end process CurStDecode_RX;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
last_value:process (CLK, RESETn, APPEND_CRC)
begin
if (RESETn = '0') then
    last_append <= '1';
elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then
    last_append <= APPEND_CRC;
end if;
end process last_value;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Using the current state of the counter and the input signals
-- decide what the next state should be
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NxStDecode_Tx:process (curr_st, APPEND_CRC, last_append)
begin
-- FSM
case curr_st is
    when idle_st=>
        if APPEND_CRC = '1' and last_append = '0' then
            next_st <= delay_crc;
        else
            next_st <= idle_st;
        end if;
    when delay_crc =>
            next_st <= result;
    when result =>              
        next_st <= idle_st;     
    when others =>
        next_st <= idle_st;
end case;                               
 end process NxStDecode_Tx;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Using the current state of the counter 
 -- decide what the output should be
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OuStDecode_Tx:process (curr_st) 
begin
  case (curr_st) is
        when idle_st =>
        appended_crc <= '0';
    when delay_crc =>
        appended_crc <= '0';
        when result => 
        appended_crc <= '1';
        when others => 
        appended_crc <= '0';
end case;                               
end process OuStDecode_Tx;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- output appended frame                                       
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 process (RESETn, CLK, appended_crc, frame_to_append, crc_result_tx)
 begin
  if (RESETn = '0') then
    frame_to_output <= (others => '0');
elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then
  if (appended_crc = '1') then               
        frame_to_output(39 downto 0)  <= frame_to_append(39 downto 0);
    frame_to_output(47 downto 40) <= crc_result_tx;
  end if;
end if;
end process ;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- output signals                                            
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TX_FRAME <= frame_to_output;
  frame_to_append <= TX_FRAME_NO_CRC;
 CRC_APPENDED <= appended_crc;
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
end arch;
```

Comment: Static timing analysis will tell you the slowest path. Rewrite that or re-pipeline it.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more on what @BrianDrummond suggested, try registering your signals that go between the two components (RX and TX).  I guess this would be the CRC_APPENDED and TX_FRAME signals.  This will allow the tools more time to satisfy propagation delay and setup times and can help achieve faster speeds.  BTW, when you say "when I test either on its own..." you are referring to the results of your synthesis tools I assume?

Comment: "when I test either on its own...", I mean that post-layout sim is ok, and layout gives me 200+ MHz speed. Not only during synthesis. I have red about registering Inputs and Outputs but, noy sure how to implement that. The TX_FRAME output, comes from the internal signal frame_to_output. That internal signal is under a clocked process. Doesn't that make my output registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to test them, back to back, my speed drops significantly (bellow 150 MHz).
>   ...
>   And just to be more precise, the limiting factor when they are both tested is, frame-to-output(Tx) to curr_state(Rx).

From this I imply that what you mean by "back-to-back" testing you mean you connect the Tx Output to the Rx Input. As [Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922723/russell) says, you need to review the `CRC_APPENDED` and `TX_FRAME` paths between Tx and Rx:
- `TX_FRAME` (the Tx Output) is registered on output in the Tx Block. I will assume it goes straight to the CRC Decoder in the Rx. This path could not be re-pipelined any further.
- `CRC_APPENDED` comes straight out of the OuStDecode_Tx Mux i.e. combinational logic. Try generating `CRC_APPENDED` from a synchronous process:

```
p_crc_appended : process (CLK, RESETn)  
begin  
   if(RESETn = 0) then
      CRC_APPENDED <= '0';
   elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then  
      CRC_APPENDED <= appended_crc;  
   end if;  
end process;
```

plus, `CRC_APPENDED` and `TX_FRAME` will change on the same clock edge. Currently `CRC_APPENDED` changes one clock cycle before `TX_FRAME`.

tl;dr try registering `appended_crc` to generate `CRC_APPENDED`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I have slightly changed the design. I still use a FSM (with records) and control a passive crc. (the code posted here i consider it as active crc). The fsm with records, surely registers all outputs, so my speed loss is gone. Still though, one thing i dont understand is, "The TX_FRAME output, comes from the internal signal frame_to_output. That internal signal is under a clocked process. Doesn't that make my output registered?".

Comment: Yes, the output `TX_FRAME` is indeed registered since there is no logic between the registered process' output (i.e. FF output) and the entity port.  `CRC_APPENDED` was not registered, probably causing the timing problem when connecting Tx to Rx.